# How to add swiping dots to Tabbed/Carousel page?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm wondering how to add dots indicating to swipe screens in either `TabbedPage` or `CarouselPage` like in the below image?

[image]

I tried adding images for that but they don't look natural so is there a real way for doing that?

My above workaround explanation in an example with 3 page:

I create 3 images each image has 3 dots one of them is highlighted:

First image highlighted dot is the first one.

Second image highlighted dot is the second one.

and etc.

Comment: Just use this :) https://github.com/tomh4/Carousel

Comment: Thanks for help @Depechie , but I'm wondering is Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView replaced with CarouselView.FormsPlugin as I can't find anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView and write a user control for page indicators. Follow the steps below,

Using Package Console, Install-Package Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView -Version 2.3.0-pre2 (Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView) package from NuGet in all 3 projects (PCL, iOS and Android).

add reference to Carousel view in the page directives,

```
xmlns:cv="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView"
```

and the Xaml code as below,

```
 <StackLayout  Padding="0,0,0,5" BackgroundColor="#d8d8d8" >
     <cv:CarouselView x:Name="cview" ItemsSource="{Binding DataSource}" Position="{Binding Position, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <cv:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>       
            <Image  Aspect="AspectFill" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Source="{Binding PickedImage}" />
          </DataTemplate>
        </cv:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
      </cv:CarouselView>
  <cutomControl:CarouselIndicators IndicatorHeight="16" IndicatorWidth="16" UnselectedIndicator="unselected_circle.png" SelectedIndicator="selected_circle.png" Position="{Binding Position}" ItemsSource="{Binding DataSource}" />
</StackLayout>
```

notice, Position and your viewmodel should have,

```
private int _position;
    public int Position
    {
        get { return _position; }
        set
        {
            _position = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

notice, customControl below CarouselView.. Yes, you need to write a custom control for it. Just use the below custom control code and add reference in the page directive,

so your page directive will be as below,

```
 xmlns:cutomControl="clr-namespace:XXXX.CustomControls;assembly=XXXX"
 xmlns:cv="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView"
```

and the custom control code is,

```
public class CarouselIndicators : Grid
{
    private ImageSource UnselectedImageSource = null;
    private ImageSource SelectedImageSource = null;
    private readonly StackLayout _indicators = new StackLayout() { Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand };

    public CarouselIndicators()
    {
        this.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand;
        this.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = GridLength.Auto });
        this.Children.Add(_indicators);
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty PositionProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Position), typeof(int), typeof(CarouselIndicators), 0, BindingMode.TwoWay, propertyChanging: PositionChanging);
    public static readonly BindableProperty ItemsSourceProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ItemsSource), typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(CarouselIndicators), Enumerable.Empty<object>(), BindingMode.OneWay, propertyChanged: ItemsChanged);
    public static readonly BindableProperty SelectedIndicatorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(SelectedIndicator), typeof(string), typeof(CarouselIndicators), "", BindingMode.OneWay);
    public static readonly BindableProperty UnselectedIndicatorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(UnselectedIndicator), typeof(string), typeof(CarouselIndicators), "", BindingMode.OneWay);
    public static readonly BindableProperty IndicatorWidthProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IndicatorWidth), typeof(double), typeof(CarouselIndicators), 0.0, BindingMode.OneWay);
    public static readonly BindableProperty IndicatorHeightProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IndicatorHeight), typeof(double), typeof(CarouselIndicators), 0.0, BindingMode.OneWay);

    public string SelectedIndicator
    {
        get { return (string)this.GetValue(SelectedIndicatorProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(SelectedIndicatorProperty, value); }
    }

    public string UnselectedIndicator
    {
        get { return (string)this.GetValue(UnselectedIndicatorProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(UnselectedIndicatorProperty, value); }
    }

    public double IndicatorWidth
    {
        get { return (double)this.GetValue(IndicatorWidthProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(IndicatorWidthProperty, value); }
    }

    public double IndicatorHeight
    {
        get { return (double)this.GetValue(IndicatorHeightProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(IndicatorHeightProperty, value); }
    }

    public int Position
    {
        get { return (int)this.GetValue(PositionProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(PositionProperty, value); }
    }

    public IEnumerable ItemsSource
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable)this.GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, (object)value); }
    }

    private void Clear()
    {
        _indicators.Children.Clear();
    }

    private void Init(int position)
    {

        if (UnselectedImageSource == null)
            UnselectedImageSource = ImageSource.FromFile(UnselectedIndicator);

        if (SelectedImageSource == null)
            SelectedImageSource = ImageSource.FromFile(SelectedIndicator);

        if (_indicators.Children.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _indicators.Children.Count; i++)
            {
                if (((Image)_indicators.Children[i]).ClassId == nameof(State.Selected) && i != position)
                    _indicators.Children[i] = BuildImage(State.Unselected, i);
                else if (((Image)_indicators.Children[i]).ClassId == nameof(State.Unselected) && i == position)
                    _indicators.Children[i] = BuildImage(State.Selected, i);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var enumerator = ItemsSource.GetEnumerator();
            int count = 0;
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                Image image = null;
                if (position == count)
                    image = BuildImage(State.Selected, count);
                else
                    image = BuildImage(State.Unselected, count);

                _indicators.Children.Add(image);

                count++;
            }
        }
    }

    private Image BuildImage(State state, int position)
    {
        var image = new Image()
        {
            WidthRequest = IndicatorWidth,
            HeightRequest = IndicatorHeight,
            ClassId = state.ToString()
        };

        switch (state)
        {
            case State.Selected:
                image.Source = SelectedImageSource;
                break;
            case State.Unselected:
                image.Source = UnselectedImageSource;
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception("Invalid state selected");
        }

        image.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer() { Command = new Command(() => { Position = position; }) });

        return image;
    }

    private static void PositionChanging(object bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var carouselIndicators = bindable as CarouselIndicators;

        carouselIndicators.Init(Convert.ToInt32(newValue));
    }

    private static void ItemsChanged(object bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var carouselIndicators = bindable as CarouselIndicators;

        carouselIndicators.Clear();
        carouselIndicators.Init(0);
    }

    public enum State
    {
        Selected,
        Unselected
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't find Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView assembly is it replaced with CarouselView.FormsPlugin?

Comment: Ah.. forgot to mention.. you need to add Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView package from NuGet in all 3 projects (PCL, iOS and Android)...

Comment: Thanks for help Abdul Gani, I actually mean I don't find it in NuGet.

Comment: try this command from package console Install-Package Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView -Version 2.3.0-pre2

Comment: May you please explain what `DataSource` and `Position` of the `CarouselView` and `CarouselIndicators` should be?

Comment: Datasource is a list of entity that has the data of the carousel page like image, title, subtitle etc.. Position is a property which will have the current carousel page index. When you change the carousel page, the position property will be triggered which will update carousel indicator position (.i.e. changing the dots position as per the selected carousel page.

Comment: Thanks for help Abdul Gani, but how to replace that `Image` with `ContentPage` like `CarouselPage` does?

Comment: You can replace with any layout like Stack or Grid to create your intented designs

Comment: It's sad that I can't replace with `ContentPage` , but can you please tell me how to bind the layouts, I've added `MyStack` property to `CarouselData`and in xaml code replaced `Image` with `StackLayout` and set `BindingContext="{Binding MyStack}"` but didn't work so how to bind that?

Comment: Is that even doable or trying another strategy?

Comment: Sure here it is: https://github.com/AhmedSalahKhodair/Xamarin.Forms-CarouselView-Sample

Comment: Please upload with a sample solution whatever you have done with some sample data.. To integrate these files itself will take time..I'm finding time in between my busy schedule. hope you understand..

Comment: Thank you so much to you. it's uploading now it's 204 MB so unfortunately it will take some time.

Comment: Sorry for being late because of internet problems but the entire solution is uploaded now on: https://github.com/AhmedSalahKhodair/XamarinFormsCarouselViewSample

Comment: I just gone through your code. Just replace the below code with your DataTemplate of the CarouselView.

Comment: <DataTemplate>

                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="0,20,0,0" Spacing="40">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
                    </StackLayout>

                </DataTemplate>

Comment: It won't work with me as my pages elements are different to each other so I need different `StackLayout`s for each page thus I want to bind the whole `StackLayout`.

Comment: For this, you need to have multiple data templates and select using template selector.

Comment: Thanks for help, data template selector worked and repository is updated now with it.

Comment: But it has some issue, when I added a custom rendered picker to some view and open that picker, that picker make swiping to first view, why that even happen?
    I've also noticed that while `CustomDataTemplateSelector` is called at first time that `OnSelectTemplate` is invoked 2 times one for 1st view and second for 2nd view regardless the number of views?

Comment: I have opened an issue with that on GitHub.